# How to read a saml with next js client?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, iframe

I have a serverless nextjs+react application which is opened from an iframe page. When a link is clicked on an iframe page, it opens up my application.
Now during this process before opening the iframe communicates with an SSO authenticator and sends the response to my app.
1.the response is a SAML
2.the saml is sent to my app in the request body.
3.eg:my app runs with url http://hybrid/mmk/object/details
4. The above url is hit by the iframe page to open my app.
5.now my nextjs +react app doesnt have a server as it runs on ibm websphere

So question is,
1.how do i read the SAML using my next app from the request body?